# NServicebus retry message more than MaxEntries setting

Tags: nservicebus

even if i set the MaxRetries to 1, in case of error the message is retried N times, such 5 or 6 times.

Is it a bug ?

Is it possible to disable the retry mechanism so when error happens the message is moved to the errors queue instantly ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of NSB are you using?

Comment: Hi Andreas, NSB version is 2.0.0.1145.

Answer (score 0):

I've verified that this is working as expected in both 2.6 and 3.X so I suggest that you upgrade your NServiceBus version